# Control Flow of switch statements without breaks

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have a question regarding the following switch statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    switch (x)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "x is 1" << endl;
            //break;
        case 2:
            cout << "x is 2" << endl;
            //break;

        default:
            cout << "x is something else" << endl;
    }

}
```

With break it works as expected but when I comment out the breaks the output is:

> x is 1
>   x is 2
>   x is something else

I expect the output to be

> x is 1
>   x is something else

because x == 1 and case 1 is executed. Without a break it also checks case 2 which should not be executed because x != 2. At the end default is executed.

Why is case 2 executed in this case?

Comment: Because it falls through - that's why you added the `break`s in the first place

Comment: *"Without a break it also checks case 2 ..."* no it doesn't check case 2, it just executes the code with no more case checking.

Comment: By the way, the reference explains it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` labels of `switch` operator don't "check" anything, they're basically `goto` labels. One could even write:

```
const int count = 12;
char dest[count], src[count] = "abracadabra", *from = src, *to = dest;
int n = 1 + (count - 1) / 8;
switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do { *to++ = *from++;
    case 7:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 6:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 5:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 4:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 3:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 2:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 1:      *to++ = *from++;
               } while (--n > 0);
}
printf("%s\n", dest);
```